# Python Code to Read Values after a Specific Header

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

Suppose we have a text file with the following:

```
nope
this one
24 25
nope again
```

I'd like to go past a line, `this one`, and take values on the line, so `24` and `25`. 
I have this done in some old Fortran code and would love to have a Python 3 replication. Here's what it'd be in Fortran:

```
subroutine read_until(unit, string, error)
    implicit none
    integer, parameter           :: long_max=128
    integer,          intent(in) :: unit
    character(len=*), intent(in) :: string
    character(len=long_max)      :: control
    logical, optional            :: error
    if (PRESENT(error)) error =.FALSE.
    rewind(unit)
    do while (.TRUE.)
        read(unit,'(64A)',ERR=11,end=22) control
        if (trim(adjust(control))==string) return
    end do
    return
11  write(*,*) ' Error when reading data file '
    if (present(error)) error=.TRUE.
    return
end subroutine read_until

open(11, file = data.txt, form = 'formatted', status = 'unknown')
call read_until(11, "this one")
read (11,*) first_val, second_val
```

So, find the line after a header, then start reading values separated by whitespace on the line.

Comment: Stack overflow is not a code-writing service. Give it a shot and we will be happy to help when you've hit a wall. Good luck!

Comment: Oh shoot! Am I in the wrong channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to write this is to just loop over the lines:

```
with open('data.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.strip() == 'this one':
            break
    else:
        raise ValueError('Header not found!')
```

… and now, the next line in the file is the one we want to parse, so:

```
    line = next(f)
    first_val, second_val = line.strip().split()
```

Of course in Python, these values won't be automatically converted to integers; you have to do that manually:

```
    first_val, second_val = int(first_val), int(second_val)
```

But that's it, modulo handling those `ValueError`s (the explicit one, and the ones raised if `split` returns too many or too few strings and if the integers aren't actually integers) and maybe IO errors.

Comment: Is it okay if I add to my question my application of your answer?

Answer (score 1):

An open file handle in Python is an iterator. Use this fact!

```
with open("filename") as infile: 
   for line in infile: # Iterate through the file
     if line.strip() == 'this one': # Find the marker
       x, y = next(infile).split() # Go to the next line
       break
int(x)
#24
int(y)
#25
```

You can make the code even more compact by incorporating the datatype conversion into the body of the loop:

```
x, y = map(int, next(infile).split())
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use readline() to read a line, and make a while loop

```
def line_after():
    with open("/file_path/filename", "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        while true:
           if "this one" in f.readline():
               a, b = f.readline().split()
               return int(a), int(b)
        return None
```

Comment: How would this method look though an unknown number of values to take though? Would I just take the readline.split stuff out and do them externally?

Comment: `f.readline().split()` returns a list of strings. If you need to turn it into a list of ints, you can do : values = [int(string) for string in f.readline().split()]